# minor problem with control structure not executing code the way I want it to

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Making a game us JS  which selects a winner based on who gets to a certain number the first. however when I implement an if statement it breaks my game as this IF statement is to merely stop the game as soon as a winner has been selected.

when I remove the if statement the code works and selects a winner however, you can still keep clicking on the dice roll button and this is not what I want to happen here. Thank you in advance!

```
var scores, roundScore, currentPlayer, playTime;
game();

document.querySelector(".btn-roll").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (playTime) {
    // 1. random number generator
    var dice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    console.log(dice);

    // 2. display the result
    var diceDom = document.querySelector(".dice");
    diceDom.style.display = "block";
    diceDom.src = "/images/dice-" + dice + ".png";

    // 3. update the round score if the rolled number was not a 1

    if (dice !== 1) {
      // i. add score
      roundScore += dice;
      document.querySelector(
        "#current-" + currentPlayer
      ).textContent = roundScore;
    } else {
      // ii. next player
      nextPlayer();
    }
  }
});

document.querySelector(".btn-hold").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (playTime) {
    // 4. add current players score to global score
    scores[currentPlayer] += roundScore;

    // i. update UI
    document.querySelector("#score-" + currentPlayer).textContent =
      scores[currentPlayer];

    // ii. check who one the game
    if (scores[currentPlayer] >= 10) {
      document.querySelector("#name-" + currentPlayer).textContent =
        "You are the winner!";
      document.querySelector(".dice").style.display = "none";
      document
        .querySelector(".player-" + currentPlayer + "-panel")
        .classList.add("winner");
      document
        .querySelector(".player-" + currentPlayer + "-panel")
        .classList.remove(".active");
      playTime = false;
    } else {
      // iii. next player

      nextPlayer();
    }
  }
});

function nextPlayer() {
  currentPlayer === 0 ? (currentPlayer = 1) : (currentPlayer = 0);
  roundScore = 0;

  //iii. reset scores to 0
  document.getElementById("current-0").textContent = "0";
  document.getElementById("current-1").textContent = "0";

  //iiii. toggle active class for selected player
  document.querySelector(".player-0-panel").classList.toggle("active");

  document.querySelector(".player-1-panel").classList.toggle("active");

  //iiiii. remove dice image when new player is appointed
  document.querySelector(".dice").style.display = "none";
}
document.querySelector(".btn-new").addEventListener("click", game);

function game() {
  scores = [0, 0];
  currentPlayer = 0;
  roundScore = 0;

  // hide dice on intital page load
  document.querySelector(".dice").style.display = "none";

  // reset scores to 0
  document.getElementById("score-0").textContent = "0";
  document.getElementById("score-1").textContent = "0";
  document.getElementById("current-0").textContent = "0";
  document.getElementById("current-1").textContent = "0";
  document.getElementById("name-0").textContent = "Player 1";
  document.getElementById("name-1").textContent = "Player 2";
  // reset colour of player panels
  document.querySelector(".player-0-panel").classList.remove("winner");
  document.querySelector(".player-1-panel").classList.remove("winner");
  document.querySelector(".player-0-panel").classList.remove("active");
  document.querySelector(".player-1-panel").classList.remove("active");
  // re adding the active class
  document.querySelector(".player-1-panel").classList.add("active");
}
```

I am expecting the If statement (playTime) which is located just under the queryselector '.btn-roll' to stop the game as soon as the winner is announced. but instead it is just not allowing this part of the code to run

Comment: I can't find a place where `playTime` becomes `true`

Comment: Whenever the game begins, the scores of both the players are initialised, then the payTime should become true. When the player reaches 10, the payTime should turn back to False and scores should reset. Then only the game can automatically stop in the above code

Comment: Well, according to the code the game stops only when `.btn-hold` is clicked. There is no more `playTime = false`. So, the game cycle is looking like this: starts by clicking `.btn-new`, the first player is welcomed to press `.btn-roll` after it the second player clicks the same button and so on. Tell me, when `.btn-hold` is clicked?

Comment: Hi Ivan- the game stops when a winner is determined when the scores[currentPlayer] value is greater than 10 the issue lies in the first block of code under the query selectory '.btn-roll' the if playtime structure seems not to be allowing the game to commence however if I remove it you are able to play the game but as soon as a winner is announced (someone has score 10 or more) the game does not stop and you are able to continue- ruining the gae, and thats the issue